# Нарисовать строку в прямоугольнике

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Есть небольшая строка без '\n' и координаты прямоугольника. Нужно отобразить строку максимально большим шрифтом при котором, она **не вылезает за границы прямоугольника.** Как это сделать?

Бинарный поиск с помощью [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h597fsh.aspx) не предлагать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обосновать, что в общем случае не существует простого способоа отображения пары `{ Текст, Ширина текста на экране }` в `{ Размер шрифта }.`

Это так, поскольку для того, чтобы вычислить ширину финальной строчки, необходимо знать *ширину* каждого из глифов, параметры их *кернинга* и *спейсинга.*

Все эти параметры зависят от размера шрифта, но такая зависимость обычно нелинейна и достаточно сложна для того, чтобы анализировать ее в своем коде *(этим занимаются библиотеки типа `libpango` и вообще все рендереры шрифтов, если интересно, то можете начать изучение с [**описания формата truetype**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType))*.

---

*Теперь ближе к задаче:*

Когда мы знаем, что написать неитеративный алгоритм для вычисления размера шрифта не получится, попробуем написать *итеративный* алгоритм, который хорошо работает на практике.

> **Предположим, что ширина текста все-таки увеличивается пропорционально
> размеру шрифта.**
>
> В реальности, конечно, это не так, однако в для большинства шрифтов можно полагать, что > зависимость линейная и погрешность находится в пределах `epsilon`-окрестности.

---

Тогда нужный размер шрифта для известной `Width` *(при известной гарнитуре шрифта, например, `Verdana`)* можно получить следующим образом:

- Возьмем случайный размер шрифта `TryFontSize`, но в разумных пределах (например, `14pt`).
- Измерим ширину надписи с помощью метода `MeasureString` этим размером шрифта, назовем ее `TryWidth`, далее посмотрим, насколько она больше / меньше, чем `Width`.
- Откорректируем следующее приближение, основываясь на предположении о линейности. То есть `ApproximatedFontSize = TryWidth / Width * TryFontSize`.
- Вычислим ширину надписи для `ApproximatedFontSize`, она уже будет являться хорошим приближением для финального результата.
- Применим любой алгоритм поиска вверх или вниз с помощью `MeasureWidth`, чтобы получить **точный размер** нашего шрифта. Тут подойдет даже линейный поиск, поскольку количество итераций должно быть небольшим. *Фактически, этим шагом мы убираем `epsilon`-погрешность нашего предположения.*

---